# Why does OS X not have a default package manager?

Tags: packaging, macos, package-managers

Debian has APT. Red Hat has RPM. FreeBSD has Ports. NetBSD has pkgsrc. Mac OS X has MacPorts, Fink, and Homebrew, but those are all third-party package managers. Why does OS X not have a default package manager?

Comment: Interesting question but not really programming related.

Answer (score 5):

It does - its called the App Store.